# How to pass parameters to cypher transaction queries in py2neo

Tags: py2neo

I have a variable named 'label' and I want to pass that as a parameter to cypher transactions append method so that I can build a cypher query to execute.

I have tried something similar to below:

```
session = cypher.Session(uri)
tx = session.create_transaction()
tx.append("CREATE INDEX ON :{label}(id)", {'label': 'Person'})  
tx.commit()
```

But this is throwing the below error:

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.InvalidSyntax: Invalid input '{': expected whitespace or a label name (line 1, column 18)
"CREATE INDEX ON :{label}(id)"
              ^
```

Can you please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter passing syntax is correct but labels (and relationship types) cannot be parameterised in Cypher.

Comment: I ran into the same problem. Is there any particular reason why it can't be?

Comment: It's a limitation of the Cypher engine which is AFAIK related to query planning.